# How to draw a grid line which makes clickable squares on google map in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, clone

I want to clone what3words app using flutter. Can anyone here guide me how to approach drawing a clickable squares on google map? Plus, I also want to show the grid line once a user zoom in google map with certain degree.

[image]

Comment: have you found the solution bro

Comment: did you find the solution??